# Can't parse XML soap from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, soap, xquery

Please help with parsing values with SQL from XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
               xmlns:pac="http://www.axelot.ru/ESB/package"
               xmlns:esb="http://esb.axelot.ru">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <pac:PushMessage>
            <pac:message>
                <esb:Body>
                    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"?>
                    <classData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <GUID/>
                        <SynonymID>46</SynonymID>
                        <BatchID>2CXPN6700PB9GZ4F2O0E6Y3A8</BatchID>
                        <ItemNo>8860637</ItemNo>
                        <OrderID/>
                        <OrderLineID>0</OrderLineID>
                        <NetWeight>60.900</NetWeight>
                        <GrossWeight>63.900</GrossWeight>
                        <ProductionDate>2023-11-06T16:27:33</ProductionDate>
                        <AdvanceDate/>
                        <TerminalID>0</TerminalID>
                        <ProcessUnit>2</ProcessUnit>
                        <SystemType>3</SystemType>
                        <Destination>7</Destination>
                        <CarcassStateCategory>560ec6f3-d352-11ed-bbdd-0050568ed6c5</CarcassStateCategory>
                        <NetWeightDCP06>61.600</NetWeightDCP06>
                    </classData>]]>
                </esb:Body>
                <esb:ClassId>DCP18</esb:ClassId>
                <esb:CreationTime>2023-11-07T10:36:25</esb:CreationTime>
                <esb:Id>3e52661f-c858-4db5-8100-cc0cda7e2a9f</esb:Id>
                <esb:NeedAcknowledgment>false</esb:NeedAcknowledgment>
                <esb:Properties/>
                <esb:Receivers/>
                <esb:ReplyTo/>
                <esb:Source/>
                <esb:Type>DTP</esb:Type>
                <esb:CorrelationId xsi:nil="true"
                                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            </pac:message>
        </pac:PushMessage>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to parse this values from XML:

```
BatchID :2CXPN6700PB9GZ4F2O0E6Y3A8
ItemNo: 8860637
ClassId: DCP18<
Id: 3e52661f-c858-4db5-8100-cc0cda7e2a9f
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Notable points:

- You need to declare and use XML namespaces.
- CData section needs special treatment. First, cast it as XML data type. After
  that business as usual.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
               xmlns:pac="http://www.axelot.ru/ESB/package"
               xmlns:esb="http://esb.axelot.ru">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <pac:PushMessage>
            <pac:message>
                <esb:Body><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"?>
                    <classData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <GUID/>
                        <SynonymID>46</SynonymID>
                        <BatchID>2CXPN6700PB9GZ4F2O0E6Y3A8</BatchID>
                        <ItemNo>8860637</ItemNo>
                        <OrderID/>
                        <OrderLineID>0</OrderLineID>
                        <NetWeight>60.900</NetWeight>
                        <GrossWeight>63.900</GrossWeight>
                        <ProductionDate>2023-11-06T16:27:33</ProductionDate>
                        <AdvanceDate/>
                        <TerminalID>0</TerminalID>
                        <ProcessUnit>2</ProcessUnit>
                        <SystemType>3</SystemType>
                        <Destination>7</Destination>
                        <CarcassStateCategory>560ec6f3-d352-11ed-bbdd-0050568ed6c5</CarcassStateCategory>
                        <NetWeightDCP06>61.600</NetWeightDCP06>
                    </classData>]]>
                </esb:Body>
                <esb:ClassId>DCP18</esb:ClassId>
                <esb:CreationTime>2023-11-07T10:36:25</esb:CreationTime>
                <esb:Id>3e52661f-c858-4db5-8100-cc0cda7e2a9f</esb:Id>
                <esb:NeedAcknowledgment>false</esb:NeedAcknowledgment>
                <esb:Properties/>
                <esb:Receivers/>
                <esb:ReplyTo/>
                <esb:Source/>
                <esb:Type>DTP</esb:Type>
                <esb:CorrelationId xsi:nil="true"
                                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            </pac:message>
        </pac:PushMessage>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'
    , 'http://www.axelot.ru/ESB/package' AS pac
    , 'http://esb.axelot.ru' AS esb)
SELECT x.value('(/*:classData/*:BatchID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS BatchID
    , x.value('(/*:classData/*:ItemNo/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS ItemNo
    , c.value('(esb:ClassId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS ClassId
    , c.value('(esb:Id/text())[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS Id
FROM @xml.nodes('/Envelope/Body/pac:PushMessage/pac:message') AS t(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST(c.value('(esb:Body/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS XML)) AS t1(x);
```

**Output**

| BatchID | ItemNo | ClassId | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2CXPN6700PB9GZ4F2O0E6Y3A8 | 8860637 | DCP18 | 3E52661F-C858-4DB5-8100-CC0CDA7E2A9F |

Comment: That's good, ty!

Comment: Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. 
Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"